# HTML element offset change detect using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am creating a custom dropdown control and facing issue with the value popup position.

When I scrolling the page/parent div , the base input box position got changed, if value popup is open , then it not changing the position at all.

I have added window scroll event, but its not triggering as, scroll is happening in div level.

Again that div is made dynamically, so don't have direct access to that.

If there are any way to detect my base input box position changed, so that I can handle this problem.

Comment: `that div is made dynamically, so don't have direct access to that` - if it's in the DOM, you have direct access to it if you know how

Comment: I am creating a dropdown means, its a generic control. It can be any dom hierarchy. How can I detect , which parent dom scrolling?

Comment: you need to show us some code